# SQL syntax on Autohotkey

Tags: mysql, autohotkey

Can anyone tell me the error???

```
sql = ( select trim(last_name) as Last_Name, trim(first_name) as First_name, trim(middle_name) as Middle_Name,long_posname as Position from tb_crew_master join tb_position on (tb_position.posID = tb_crew_master.posID) where last_name like '%' . '%sname%' . '%')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found issues with the quotes, please try improving quotes, as follows

```
sql = ("select trim(last_name) as Last_Name, trim(first_name) as First_name,  
trim(middle_name) as Middle_Name,long_posname as Position 
from 
tb_crew_master 
join 
tb_position on (tb_position.posID = tb_crew_master.posID)
where 
last_name like '%".%sname%."%'")
```

Comment: thanks... but i got this error message after that

Error at line 81.

The following variable name contains an illegal character:
""."

The program will exit.

that is the error...

Comment: try last_name like '%". %sname% ."%'"   i.e add some space   or   last_name like '%". sname ."%'" i.e.  sname without %

Comment: it just treating the sname as a text not a variable...by the way, thanks for your effort on helping me here...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use assignment with `:=`, the variable does not need the `%` symbols. If you want to use assignment with `=`, in this case you must use ` as an escape character.  The sql and sql2 lines below are the same.

```
sname := "ThisName"
sql := "select trim(last_name) from tb_crew_master where last_name like '%" . sname . "%'"
sql2 = select trim(last_name) from tb_crew_master where last_name like '`%%sname%`%'
msgbox % sql "`n" sql2
```